# Designing Database Schema for Schedule of Classes

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to design a database schema to model a University's schedule of classes.  Usually classes run either MWF or TuTh.  Implementation will be done using MySQL.  What would be the best way to design the tables for handling what days/times classes take place?  My current tables look like this:

```
Time
  int TimeID (primary key)
  Time ClassStartTime
  Time ClassEndTime
  int DaysOfWeekID (foreign key)

DaysOfWeek
  int DaysOfWeekID (primary key)
  varchar DaysOfWeek
```

This above Time table would link to the 'Class' table on TimeID.  I feel like there would be a better way of doing this however, especially when handling the days of the week.  Having a dedicated 'days of week' type would be better for parsing on the front end as I plan on implementing a calendar with the database.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever you choose, I strongly recommend ***against*** a single value holding multiple items of data.  Instead of one string holding "TuTh", for example, you should (in my opinion) have two records keyed against on foreign key or possibly 7 fields flagged true/false.  It *can* be a good idea to enumerate the combinations of a limitted set, but I'd still map each individual day against the composite-group, rather than have a string to hold multiple items of data.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach class can start any day of the week and different days of weeks can run to different hours.  Some classes have a "LAB" which runs MWRF or MTWF. with labs on tues/thursday.  The Downfall to this approach is that you have to record start/end time for EACH day.

```
Class
  ClassID

DaysofWeek
DaysOfWeekID

ClassHours
ClassID
DaysofWeekID
StartTime
EndTime
```

A class has zero or many class hours.
A class hours belongs to one and only one class
a class hours belongs to one day of week and only one day of week
A DayofWeek belongs to Zero to many class hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to model this. A lot depends on what the data looks like - for example, you say classes "usually" run either MWF or TuTh - and a lot depends what you plan to do with it.

Something like this might work:

```
Class
  Id int (PK)
  StartTime Time
  EndTime Time

Class_DayOfWeek
  ClassId int (FK)
  DayOfWeekId int (FK)

DayOfWeek
  Id int (PK)
  Name varchar -- Monday, Tuesday, etc.
```

You would need to go even further if classes meet at different times on different days. And you would need to go a lot further if you want to handle scheduling resources (like instructors and classrooms) ... but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Comma delimited lists in relational databases is a very dangerous anti-pattern.  Could you enumerate the relative advantages and dis-advantages of this approach?  As that part of the answer currently stands, I must make the comment `avoid such options whenever possible`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought about it a bit and decided that I agree with you. I would almost never use the comma-delimited values in my own design, so I probably shouldn't recommend it to others. I've updated my answer. Cheers!